# Data Driven multiple photos from point layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.5, data-driven-pages, photos

In Arcmap 10.5, I am trying to use data driven pages to display multiple pictures in a photo point layer based on an overlaying polygon index. 
I would like to use the yellow polygon layer as the index, shifting between each field. And would like to display the attached pictures from the photo point layer that the index is currently showing.

The first image is 2 fields with a few photo points shown. Using data driven pages, I have selected the polygon layer as my index. 
[image: Image 1]
Image 1 – Photo points layer in pink, polygon index layer in yellow.

I would like to export a map book of each field with the corresponding photos. I have tried to use the photo points as the index but then end up with 3 maps per field.

[image: Image 2]
Image 2 – Field 1 with 3 photos displayed

[image: Image 3]
Image 3 – Field 2 with 3 photos displayed

I have tried spatial joining the layers, but it does not join the attachments or the paths, so I cant display the pictures. I have also tried to set up 2 data frames but using the polygon index does not shift the photo indexes.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would do this using ArcPy and a search cursor on an index feature class to create your pages without using Data Driven Pages.

Comment: Add photos as attachments to your pages. In attachment table change their names to be the same, e.g. photo1.jpg. insert any picture into layout and set it source to page attachment.